# Wireshark не ловит пакеты BitTorrent?

Tags: wireshark

Я пытаюсь ловить пакеты протокола BitTorrent, но Wireshark ловит только некоторые из сообщений этого протокола ( в количестве 1-5, не больше ). Ловит только сообщения типа: HandShake, Have
Сообщения типа Request и т.п не ловит. Использовал uTorrent, а потом Mono-Torrent ( последний это имплементация BitTorrent на языке C# ). В каждом из этих случаев выше результат был одинаково плох.
Пытался запускать от админа WireShark - ничего не изменилось. Информации в интернете не нашел ( гуглил не только на русском ).
Может кто знает в чём дело?

Comment: Может, вы их не на том сетевом интерфейсе ловите?

Comment: Когда я захожу в WireShark, то у меня есть только один вариант: Ethernet.

Comment: @andreymal Т.е этот вариант хоть и вполне возможный, но в моём случае он исключается.

Comment: Тогда не знаю, у меня ловит. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bxbhi.png // Может, вы их отфильтровали каким-то неправильным фильтром?

Comment: @andreymal А, так оно в формате TCP идет в Wireshark? А я всё вылупился только в Type: BitTorrent и смотрю

Comment: Нет, UDP. . . .

Comment: @andreymal А, да, ошибся. Спасибо, что подсказали.

Comment: @andreymal Кстати, оформите свой комментарий в качестве ответа. Я поставлю хоть оценку.